Repository names are obstructed by "checkout" and "pull/push" buttons in Source Control
I have a multi-root workspace in Visual Studio Code.
The naming conventions of our branches on my projects dictate that our branch names are very long, hence obstructing the visibility of the repo name itself.

I'm not using those buttons anyway. I always do my git operations from the CLI, I just want to use the Source Control view to see the diffs.
The main issue is that many of our repositories start with the same prefix so I am not able see which repo is which because the "checkout" button covers the non-prefix part of each name. I don't need the "push/pull" buttons either next to them.
I couldn't find any setting in the default settings JSON that'd make them disappear.
Is there any way to make them disappear, or make the name fully visible?
An extension if it's not supported by Code itself?

When resizing that view VSC favors the branch name (checkout button) over the repo name.
You can make the SCM bar wide enough for you and use Ctrl+B to switch the view on/off, but now also the debug view is very wide.
Or you drag the SCM views you use to the PANEL (where the terminal is).
That is usually more wide than high.
You can change the display name of the workspace in the .code-workspace file. Every workspace has a name attribute that is used for display. But you have to change the ${workspaceFolder:name} variables.
If needed you can use a shadow copy of the .code-workspace file and modify the display name if you don't want to change the repo version. Update/Merge changes when the repo version is changed.
